# TfidfTransformer and stop words

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am importing `TfidfTransformer` from `sklearn` and trying to use `stop_word` argument, but it is showing error.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(stop_words='english')


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-1315a209c082> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
----> 2 tfidf = TfidfTransformer(stop_words='english')

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stop_words'
```

How solve this error?

Comment: The TfidfTransformer has no parameter `stop_words` according to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you intent to use `TfidfVectorizer`, which has the parameter `stop_words`. Refer the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```